# Multiplying number from html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, file

I'm trying to multiply a number provided from a form in HTML by *25

```
        <label for="bagsChecked"><strong>Number of bags being checked in:</strong>
        </label>
        <input type="number" id="bagsChecked" name="bagsChecked" min="0" max="2" required>
```

I'm trying to then send it to the thanks handlebar below and display it to the user, is it possible to have it written out the same as the app.post if not how do I write it out to send to the thanks handlebar and be displayed to user

```
app.post('/checkin', function(req, res) {
res.render('thanks', {
    name: req.body.name,
    reservationID: req.body.reservationID,
    bagsChecked: req.body.bagsChecked
});
```

});

below is the thank you handlebar

```
<h1><strong>Thank you for chechking in! {{name}}</strong></h1>

<p><strong>Reservation #:{{reservationID}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>Bags Checked:{{bagsChecked}}</strong></p>
```

Comment: is this server preprocessing of a return page following a form submit? And what is a handlebar?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of where your user data is coming from so don't know if this will help but I've made a working example that illustrates typical steps for processing user data and displaying a confirmatory message using client-side javascript.

The javascript begins by making a reference to the user data object (this may have been read from a json file returned from a server on submission of a form, or could have been built client-side from form fields). The important part is to have a variable that references the data object.

Next, the relevant page elements are assigned to variables to allow their properties to be accessed (the drop-down element and an output div where the response will be rendered in this case)

**Multiplying a field value by a number**

The number of bags selected by the user is read inside an event listener when the button is pressed and assigned to the `.bagsChecked` property of the `userData` object. For completeness, I have used `parseInt()` to convert the numeric `string` read from the drop down list to a number. This is optional since javascript will *coerce* numeric strings such as `"2"` to numbers such as `2` when included in a subsequent *unambiguous* arithmetic operation. For example,  javascript will interpret `"2"*3` as `2*3` and return `6`, because multiplication has no meaning for strings. Note however, that `"2" + 3` might result in `23`, instead of `6` because `+`, as well as being an arithemetic addition operator, is also a string contatenation operator in js. That is why it's usually safer to apply `parseInt()` to numerical string. I have multiplied the number of bags by 25 to specifically address that part of your query.

Similar commands could add user name and other user data directly from page inputs if required.

The event listener then calls a function (`renderResponse`) sending the `userData` object as the sole argument.

The `renderResponse` function assembles the required html markup as a string. Javascript template literals `${variableName}` are used to place values read from the passed `data` object into the markup.

Finally, the `renderResponse` function assigns the assembled markup to the `innerHTML` property of the output element referenced earlier.

```js
// user data received from server or assembled from page user inputs;
const userData = {
 name: "Jane Smith",
 reservationID: "A23475Z",
 bagsChecked: 0
}

const outputField = document.getElementById('result');
const bagDropDownElement = document.getElementById('bagsChecked');

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName=='BUTTON') {
    userData.bagsChecked = parseInt(bagDropDownElement.value);
    renderResponse(userData);
  } // end if;
}); // end eventListener;

function renderResponse(data) {
  let markup = "";
  markup += `<h1><strong>Thank you for checking in! ${data.name.split(" ")[0]}</strong></h1>`;
  markup += `<p><strong>Reservation #:${data.reservationID}</strong></p>`;
  markup += `<p><strong>Bags Checked:${data.bagsChecked}</strong></p>`;
  markup += `<p><strong>surcharge: $${data.bagsChecked*25}</strong></p>`;

  outputField.innerHTML = markup;
} // end renderResponse function;
```

```html
<label for="bagsChecked"><strong>Number of bags being checked in:</strong></label>
<br>
<input type="number" id="bagsChecked" name="bagsChecked" min="0" max="2" required>
<button>done</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the result sent to the thank you handlebar/html to be displayed to the user instead of being displayed through javascript --- Also the user information is provided in that same form I just did not add that extra part to it. --- If i were to use form type submit would it work the same as button?

Comment: I don't know what a handlebar is. In my demonstration, the data is formatted and displayed to the user. If you're using a form, client-side javascript can collect the data before submission but the form is reset, and the data removed, once the submit button is pressed (unless javascript is used to supress the default behaviour. Usually, the server reads the sent form data and returns a preprocessed page assembled in php or similar server language.